# Do existing Javascript frameworks make sense for Typescript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frameworks, ember.js, typescript

We're about to begin work on a new web application. We're almost 100% that development will be done in Typescript rather than Javascript.

I've begun to look at frameworks / code structures that make sense for the application. Obviously most of these frameworks are written in Javascript. My worry is that these frameworks have been designed with the limitations of Javascript in mind, not strongly typed modular Typescript (e.g. Backbone's events are string names).

Are these frameworks still worth using for the structure / utility they bring? Are we going to end up fighting to make a Javascript framework work the Typescript way?

Comment: There is one big reason to keep using existing JavaScript frameworks -- you don't have to reinvent/rewrite them, and they are bug-fixed and real-life tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some libraries fit better than other and in my experience you often have to do small little tweeks to get things working - but usually it isn't a problem.

Also make sure you include the type definitions from the start of the libraries you're planning to use. You'll probably find the type definition for the library you're using as part of the [DefinitelyTyped project](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) -  there are also a number of NuGet packages with DefinitelyTyped types available.

Comment: Even though most framework have Typings-packages, no framework seems to exist yet that is optimized for TypeScripts' advantages. So even though frameworks like Angular, Ember or even ExtJS "work", the developers' experience is far from optimal. For example, most frameworks utilize a special method to "extend" a "class". This makes it difficult for the typescript-compiler to interpret what the current scope should be within a specific method. If anybody knows of a framework DESIGNED FOR TypeScript, please let me know. (I'm hoping Angular2 will be that framework)

Comment: @realbart it is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/03/05/angular-2-0-built-on-typescript.aspx

Comment: @nawfal: Ik already knew Angular2 would be rewritten in TypeScript, that's why I mentioned it. I'm just saying I hope they'll rewrite it enough to get rid of al those nasty string literals, making it very difficult to build a decent IDE.